# Adjusting style of the dialog widget from jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying make some customizations in the dialog widget from jquery-ui. For accomplish this, I include a css file with the follow content in my jsp page:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    padding: .4em 1em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    float: left;
    margin: .1em 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-decoration-color: white;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: .3em;
    top: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

which I take from example available in the official page (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), but this has no effect in the dialog when I run the application (it's displayed the same way, with the css or without it).

The complete code for the jsp page where I am using the dialog is this:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/acesso/start.jsp

Someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck using the width (and maybe height) options in the dialog API:
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width

Comment: In the example on the page, it was changed thr color of title bar. I wish accomplish at least that. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can probably use CSS to change the title bar color.  But the width tends to get set with an inline style when the dialog is opened.  If you aren't yet, I recommend using https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ to see exactly what's going on.